# ActionMailer Timing out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, actionmailer

I'm using `Rails 3.2.17` and `ActionMailer` to send out emails. In the development environment I used my google account to send email and it worked fine. On production, with the production email settings it's timing out. To verify I copied over the production settings to dev.

Currently it's failing with very little info:

```
Rendered notifications_mailer/access_granted.html.haml (2.8ms)
  Rendered notifications_mailer/access_granted.text.haml (1.5ms)
E, [2014-03-27T12:15:16.066641 #36665] ERROR -- : worker=1 PID:36673 timeout (16s > 15s), killing
E, [2014-03-27T12:15:16.079432 #36665] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 36673 SIGKILL (signal 9)> worker=1
I, [2014-03-27T12:15:16.096443 #36684]  INFO -- : worker=1 ready
```

**SMTP Settings**

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              "secure.emailsrvr.com",
  port:                 465,
  domain:               "MYDOMAIN.net",
  authentication:       :plain,
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name:            "no-reply@MYDOMAIN.net",
  password:             "MYPASSWORD"
```

I've used telnet to confirm the host and port, however when I try to send mail according to this tutorial it disconnects me.

**Telnet Console**

```
$ telnet secure.emailsrvr.com 465
Trying 166.78.79.129...
Connected to secure.emailsrvr.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
hello me
Mail from: no-reply@MYDOMAIN.net
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Additionally, I've setup my email app (Mac Mail) with this information and **AM** able to send email with these settings.

Any advice on how to approach troubleshooting this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should increase pool time in your database yml file. 
It will eliminate time out problem.

Comment: Yeah, after increasing it to 2min it completed in about 45 seconds. I'm guessing the best way to deal with this is to offload it to Delay Job or similar?

Comment: have you got your answer?