# Gitlab CE not sending email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, smtp, gitlab

I have setup Gitlab CE on a local Ubuntu Server, and I'm trying to use Zoho to send email to users. But, mails are not sent. Even when testing with `gitlab-rails console` :

```
irb(main):003:0> Notify.test_email('destination_email@address.com', 'Message Subject', 'Message Body').deliver_now
```

My SMTP config is as follow :

```
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "smtp.zoho.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 587 # I've also changed to 465, but in vain
gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = "plain"
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = "gitlab@mydomain.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = "mypassword"
gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "smtp.zoho.com"
```

And Reply by email config :

```
gitlab_rails['incoming_email_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['incoming_email_address'] = "gitlab-incoming+{key}@domain.com"
gitlab_rails['incoming_email_email'] = "gitlab@domain.com"
gitlab_rails['incoming_email_password'] = "Password"
gitlab_rails['incoming_email_host'] = "imap.zoho.com"
gitlab_rails['incoming_email_port'] = 993
gitlab_rails['incoming_email_ssl'] = true
gitlab_rails['incoming_email_mailbox_name'] = "inbox"
gitlab_rails['incoming_email_idle_timeout'] = 60
```

Can somebody help me fix this ?

**Update :** This is the output of the test in `gitlab_rails console`

> Notify#test_email: processed outbound mail in 414.5ms
>
> Sent mail to user@domain.com (65666.5ms)
>   Date: Wed, 23 Nov 2016 12:47:12 +0100
>   From: GitLab 
>   Reply-To: GitLab
>
> To: user@domain.com
>
> Message-ID: <583581c03dae3_a7303fac34cdb0fc64a7@administrateur-virtual-machine.mail>
>
> Subject: Test
>
> Mime-Version: 1.0
>
> Content-Type: text/html;
>    charset=UTF-8
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
>
> Testons
>
> Net::ReadTimeout: Net::ReadTimeout
>           from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:158:in `rbuf_fill'
>           from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:136:in`readuntil'
>           from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:146:in `readline'
>           from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/smtp.rb:946:in`recv_response'
>           from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/smtp.rb:556:in `block in do_start'
>           from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/smtp.rb:956:in`critical'
>           from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/smtp.rb:556:in `do_start'
>           from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/smtp.rb:521:in`start'
>           from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mail-2.6.4/lib/mail/network/deli          very_methods/smtp.rb:113:in `deliver!'
>           from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mail-2.6.4/lib/mail/message.rb:2          149:in`do_delivery'
>           from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mail-2.6.4/lib/mail/message.rb:2          37:in `block in deliver'
>           from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.7.1/lib/action_          mailer/base.rb:543:in`block in deliver_mail'
>           from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active          _support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
>           from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active          _support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in`instrument'
>           from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active          _support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
>           from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.7.1/lib/action_          mailer/base.rb:541:in`deliver_mail'
>           from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mail-2.6.4/lib/mail/message.rb:2          37:in `deliver'
>           from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.7.1/lib/action_          mailer/message_delivery.rb:85:in`deliver_now'
>           from (irb):1
>           from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/comma          nds/console.rb:110:in `start'
>           from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/comma          nds/console.rb:9:in`start'
>           from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/comma          nds/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
>           from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/comma          nds/commands_tasks.rb:39:in`run_command!'
>           from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/comma          nds.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
>           from bin/rails:9:in`require'
>           from bin/rails:9:in `'

Comment: no errors? nothing? what have you tried?

Comment: @pancho018 look at my update.Thanks.

Comment: @sk001 I am facing exactly same problem. It started to fail since when I updated gitlab to 9.1.3. Could you find a solution for this?

Comment: @sk001 Do you find the solution? Did you fix it? Thanks

Comment: @Farzan Do you fix your problem? If yes, how do you do it? Really thanks

Answer (score 3):

I managed to solve it with the accepted answer here: [ActionMailer "Net::ReadTimeout" when using Delayed Job with Rackspace "emailsrvr.com"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22699768/actionmailer-netreadtimeout-when-using-delayed-job-with-rackspace-emailsrvr)

It could be that some of the suggested settings in the documentation (https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/smtp.html) cause problems.

These settings work for me:

```
gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "secure.emailsrvr.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 465
gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "domain.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = "login"
gitlab_rails['smtp_tls'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = "no-reply@domain.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = "XXX"

gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_from'] = "no-reply@domain.com"
gitlab_rails['gitlab_support_email'] = "support@domain.com"
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_reply_to'] = "support@domain.com"
```

Comment: I'm using mailgun SMTP and this reference config fixed the issue!